# IllegalArgumentException:SavedStateProvider with the given key is already registered

Tags: android, kotlin, illegalstateexception, android-viewmodel, viewmodel-savedstate

My app is crashing on some user's devices with the exception below.

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: SavedStateProvider with the given key is already registered
       at androidx.savedstate.SavedStateRegistry.registerSavedStateProvider(SavedStateRegistry.java:2)
       at androidx.lifecycle.SavedStateHandleController.attachToLifecycle(SavedStateHandleController.java:2)
       at androidx.lifecycle.SavedStateHandleController.create(SavedStateHandleController.java:1)
       at androidx.lifecycle.AbstractSavedStateViewModelFactory.create(AbstractSavedStateViewModelFactory.java:1)
       at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider.get(ViewModelProvider.java:5)
       at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelLazy.getValue(ViewModelLazy.java:5)
       at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelLazy.getValue(ViewModelLazy.java:5)
       at com.emptysheet.pdfreader_autoscroll.homeScreen.MainActivity.getViewModel(MainActivity.java:3)
       at com.emptysheet.pdfreader_autoscroll.homeScreen.MainActivity$scanDeviceForFiles$1$1.invokeSuspend(MainActivity.java:3)
       at kotlin.jvm.internal.Intrinsics.checkParameterIsNotNull(Intrinsics.java)
       at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run(DispatchedTask.java:4)
       at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler.runSafely(CoroutineScheduler.java)
       at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.executeTask(CoroutineScheduler.java:7)
```

Everything is working fine on my devices. I don't get this exception on my own testing devices as well as on emulators. Also, I am using Hilt in my app.

Here is my `ViewModel` class.

```
class MainActivityViewModel @ViewModelInject constructor(
    private val pdfItemRepository: PdfItemRepository
) : ViewModel() {
  
}
```

Here is the `activity` where I use this `ViewModel`.

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

      private val viewModel:MainActivityViewModel by viewModels()


    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        
        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        val view = binding.root
        setContentView(view)

    }
```

I am not using this `MainActivityViewModel` anywhere else except `MainActivity`. So there is no sharing of ViewModel. Also, the rotation is off on `MainActivity`. So there is no rotation change.

I came to understand from the error below that somehow my activity is trying to create another ViewModel instead of retaining the previous one?. Please correct me if I am wrong. I am unable to understand what kind of scenarios is triggering `SavedStateRegistry.registerSavedStateProvider()` again.

Note - **I have omitted methods in my ViewModel class and activity to increase readability.**

Comment: What version of Lifecycle are you using? Do you see the same on the latest stable version?

Comment: Yes, I am using the current stable version of lifecycle 2.2.0. But still, I am facing this issue,

Comment: I face an similar issue, when activity destroyed.

Comment: @Rajeshkumar Could u tell us how do u resolve it ? I have the same problem ? :/

Answer (score -1):

I faced the same exception
and managed to fix that by going to **app/build.gradle** file and:

> changing the configuration name from '**annotationProcessor**' to '**kapt**'
> for these artifacts:
>
> - '**com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.28.3**',
> - '**androidx.hilt:hilt-compiler:1.0.0-alpha01**'

and sync the project.

---

You can find a useful explanation on the scenario behind the seen in the link below:
https://zsmb.co/a-deep-dive-into-extensible-state-saving/

Answer (score -1):

You must to add this dependencies to your

**implementation 'androidx.hilt:hilt-lifecycle-viewmodel:1.0.0-alpha02'**

// When using Kotlin

**kapt 'androidx.hilt:hilt-compiler:1.0.0-alpha02'**